# PostgreSQL Trigger error when performing multiple inserts

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

Looking for some advice and help with PostgreSQL Triggers. I have 3 tables I am trying to work with using a trigger.

Here are their descriptions:

```
\d staging_assets;
                Table "public.staging_assets"
       Column        |         Type          |   Modifiers   
---------------------+-----------------------+---------------
 pipe_id             | character varying(25) | not null
 kind                | character varying(25) | 
 pipe_jt_num         | character varying(25) | 
 pipe_heat           | character varying(25) | 
 pipe_length         | numeric(4,2)          | 
 pipe_wall_thickness | numeric(4,3)          | default 0.000
 degree              | numeric(4,2)          | default 0
Indexes:
    "staging_assets_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (pipe_id)
Check constraints:
    "kind_chk" CHECK (upper(kind::text) = 'BEND'::text OR upper(kind::text) = 'PIPE_JOINT'::text) NO INHERIT
Triggers:
    distinquish AFTER INSERT ON staging_assets FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE move_along()

\d bend_assets;
               Table "public.bend_assets"
     Column     |         Type          |   Modifiers   
----------------+-----------------------+---------------
 custom_id      | character varying(20) | not null
 bnd_pipe_id    | character varying(20) | 
 bnd_heat       | character varying(20) | 
 bnd_length     | numeric(3,1)          | 
 degree         | numeric(3,1)          | 
 wall_thickness | numeric(4,3)          | default 0.000
Indexes:
    "bend_assets_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (custom_id)
Check constraints:
    "bnd_len_chk" CHECK (bnd_length > 0.0)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "weld_log" CONSTRAINT "weld_log_bnd_c

onnect_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (bnd_connect) REFERENCES bend_assets(custom_id)

\d pup_assets;
                 Table "public.pup_assets"
       Column       |         Type          |   Modifiers   
--------------------+-----------------------+---------------
 custom_pup_id      | character varying(20) | not null
 pup_pipe_id        | character varying(20) | 
 pup_heat           | character varying(20) | 
 pup_length         | numeric(3,1)          | 
 pup_wall_thickness | numeric(4,3)          | default 0.000
Indexes:
    "pup_assets_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (custom_pup_id)
Check constraints:
    "pup_len_chk" CHECK (pup_length > 0.0)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "weld_log" CONSTRAINT "weld_log_pup2_connect_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (pup2_connect) REFERENCES pup_assets(custom_pup_id)
    TABLE "weld_log" CONSTRAINT "weld_log_pup_connect_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (pup1_connect) REFERENCES pup_assets(custom_pup_id)
```

My goal is that whenever a record is inserted into the `staging_assets` table, it is then also inserted into either the `pup_assets` or `bend_assets` table depending on the value found in the `staging_assets` `kind` column. I am using a `CASE` statement for the conditional logic.

Here is the trigger function I am trying so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION move_along()
 RETURNS trigger
AS $CORRECTING$
 BEGIN
 CASE 
 WHEN NEW.kind = 'BEND'
 THEN INSERT INTO bend_assets(custom_id, bnd_pipe_id, bnd_heat, bnd_length, degree, wall_thickness)
 SELECT NEW.pipe_id, NEW.pipe_jt_num, NEW.pipe_heat, NEW.pipe_length, NEW.degree, NEW.pipe_wall_thickness
 FROM staging_assets sa;
 RETURN NEW;
 WHEN NEW.kind = 'PIPE_JOINT'
 THEN INSERT INTO pup_assets(custom_pup_id, pup_pipe_id, pup_heat, pup_length, pup_wall_thickness)
 SELECT NEW.pipe_id, NEW.pipe_jt_num, NEW.pipe_heat, NEW.pipe_length, NEW.pipe_wall_thickness
 FROM staging_assets sa;
 RETURN NEW;
 ELSE
 RAISE NOTICE 'Not a valid kind type';
 END CASE;
 RETURN NULL;
 END;
$CORRECTING$
LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```

And the actual trigger definition is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER distinquish
AFTER INSERT 
ON staging_assets
FOR EACH row
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE move_along();
```

When trying a single insert for a 'PIPE_JOINT' `kind` this works and does insert the record into the `pup_assets` table:

```
INSERT INTO staging_assets
VALUES('Joint-1','PIPE_JOINT','9892','Heat-61',18.45,0.290,0);
INSERT 0 1
fab_tracking=> TABLE staging_assets;
 pipe_id |    kind    | pipe_jt_num | pipe_heat | pipe_length | pipe_wall_thickness | degree 
---------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+--------
 Joint-1 | PIPE_JOINT | 9892        | Heat-61   |       18.45 |               0.290 |   0.00
(1 row)

fab_tracking=> TABLE pup_assets;
 custom_pup_id | pup_pipe_id | pup_heat | pup_length | pup_wall_thickness 
---------------+-------------+----------+------------+--------------------
 Joint-1       | 9892        | Heat-61  |       18.5 |              0.290
(1 row)
```

Again performing a single insert for a 'BEND' `kind` value works:

```
INSERT INTO staging_assets
VALUES('Joint-2','BEND','1892','Heat-41',10.45,0.290,7.50);
INSERT 0 1
fab_tracking=> TABLE staging_assets;
 pipe_id |    kind    | pipe_jt_num | pipe_heat | pipe_length | pipe_wall_thickness | degree 
---------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+--------
 Joint-1 | PIPE_JOINT | 9892        | Heat-61   |       18.45 |               0.290 |   0.00
 Joint-2 | BEND       | 1892        | Heat-41   |       10.45 |               0.290 |   7.50
(2 rows)

fab_tracking=> TABLE bend_assets;
 custom_id | bnd_pipe_id | bnd_heat | bnd_length | degree | wall_thickness 
-----------+-------------+----------+------------+--------+----------------
 Joint-2   | 1892        | Heat-41  |       10.5 |    7.5 |          0.290
(1 row)
```

However when I try multiple inserts, I run into problems:

```
INSERT INTO staging_assets
VALUES ('Joint-3', 'BEND', '8989A', 'Heat-171', 12.33, 0.387, 5.75),
('Joint-4', 'PIPE_JOINT', '4984A', 'Heat-141', 22.33, 0.387, 0.0);

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pup_assets_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (custom_pup_id)=(Joint-4) already exists.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO pup_assets(custom_pup_id, pup_pipe_id, pup_heat, pup_length, pup_wall_thickness)
                 SELECT NEW.pipe_id, NEW.pipe_jt_num, NEW.pipe_heat, NEW.pipe_length, NEW.pipe_wall_thickness
                FROM staging_assets sa"
PL/pgSQL function move_along() line 8 at SQL statement
```

I am confused as to why I am getting the error key for unique constraint for Joint-4 in the `pup_assets` table and why the trigger is not working with multiple inserts.
When checking the `pup_assets` table, there is no Joint-4 there.

```
fab_tracking=> TABLE pup_assets;
 custom_pup_id | pup_pipe_id | pup_heat | pup_length | pup_wall_thickness 
---------------+-------------+----------+------------+--------------------
 Joint-1       | 9892        | Heat-61  |       18.5 |              0.290
(1 row)
```

Looking for any help in understanding why this is failing and how to fix it to perform with multiple inserts. I appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the `FROM staging_assets sa` part of the `INSERT` statement(s) in the trigger. Just remove it.

Comment: @ Abelisto. That did the trick for me. Thank you so much. If you will post it as an answer I can accept, I will. Thanks again.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand why you don't get the error just after the second insert (if you got where was your mistake in the code).